# Send parameters using URL syntax

Tags: python, django, url, audio, audio-player

I'm trying to use the audio player Timeside in Django 1.5. JavaScript function that handles loading the player receives this set of parameters,

loadplayer.js

```
loadPlayer function (analizerUrl, soundUrl, soundImgSize, itemId, visualizers,   CurrentUserName, isStaffOrSuperuser)
```

In my template is the following script that handles launch

```
{% If item.file %}
  loadPlayer('{% url 'item-analyze-xml' item.public_id %}',
          "{% url 'item-export' item.public_id,"mp3" %}", undefined, '{{item.id}}', visualizers,
          CURRENT_USER_NAME,  //undefined if !user.is_authenticated
          true); //true because superuser
{% Endif%}
```

URLs are configured as follows

```
url(r'^archives/items/download/(?P<public_id>[A-Za-z0-9._-]+)\.(?P<extension>'
        + export_extensions + ')$',
    item_view.item_export,
    name="item-export"),

url(r'^archives/items/(?P<public_id>[A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/analyze/xml/$',
    item_view.item_analyze_xml,
    name="item-analyze-xml"),
```

This worked in Django 1.4, attempt to update for be used in version 1.5. The problem is that I can not send the parameter MP3 here

```
"{% url 'item-export' item.public_id,"mp3" %}",
```

the view item_export is like this:

```
def item_export(self, request, public_id, extension):
```

When the player loads I get the following error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: ',' from 'pista.public_id,'
```

Which is the correct syntax for this on Django 1.5?

Using the name and equal solved this step

```
{% url 'item-export' public_id=item.public_id extension="mp3" %}
```

Seems like it is working but I have a new error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /pista/1/

Reverse for 'item-analyze-xml' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'public_id': ''}' not found.
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `"mp3"` to single quotes `'mp3'`?

Comment: Yes and didnt solve it, i have edited the post, now i know the correct syntax but im still geting a error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not want to answer my own question but I've been searching and trying a lot and I found the solution.

```
{% Url 'impromusic-item-export' item.id 'mp3'%}
```

The first quotes refer to the name of the url(everybody know), item.id can be variable depends on the object, but if I write it in quotes it will be a string of characters wich not accept any value beyond which we assign.
That's my conclusion after 5 hours of searching but I can be wrong :) hope u understand me